# How do you get back to Asgore's house after going past it in Undertale?

Tags: undertale

When I was doing a pacifist (technically neutral) route in Undertale, there was a knife inside a gift box in Asgore's house. But now that I know you have to get his health low to spare him, I really could use a weapon.

How do I get back to Asgore's house from the throne room?

Comment: Here's a map of the end level: http://i.imgur.com/ovXVuEJ.png It's got minor spoilers, but if you avoid the far top-right of the image, it shouldn't ruin anything for you.

Answer (score 6):

Walk out of the room and take the left path. Go through the cathedral where Sans judged you and keep going left. You'll eventually come to some stairs which lead back into Asgore's home.

**Ignore the elevators**. They're there for faster travel but can be confusing if you don't know where you're going. The one here will take you past Asgore's home.